# how to prevent some users to access some component by manually change the url in angular 2?

Tags: angular, datatable, routes

I'm using angular 2 and I have a data table for rendering data and a click event which redirects to `'/viewOutgoing;id=data_id'` The id is the data's id of the data table.I have some users who should not see all data in the data table. but when they change the URL to `'/viewOutgoing;id=data_id'` they can see the data, even if the data is forbidden for them. how can I handle it?
here is component.html:

```
<ngx-datatable-column prop="title">
<ng-template let-column="column" let-sort="sortFn" ngx-datatable-header-template>
  <span (click)="sort()" class="font">{{'OutgoingTable.Title' | translate}}</span>
</ng-template>
<ng-template let-value="value" let-row="row" ngx-datatable-cell-template>
  <a class="data_font" (click)="showOutgingViewForm(row.id)">{{value}}</a>
</ng-template>
```

and this is component.ts:

```
showOutgingViewForm(id) {
this.router.navigate(['/viewoutgoing', { id: id }]);
  }
```

i have a method in one of my service that i need to get a data to activate the route. i'm using:

```
 canActivate() {
    this.authService.get_user_permission().subscribe(perm => {
      if (perm.permission.rows[0].show_all = true) {
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    })
  }
}
```

and this is the service:

```
get_user_permission() {
    this.createAuthenticationHeaders();
    return this.http.get('/authentication/get_user_permission', this.options).map(res => res.json());
  }
```

and this is the get_user_permission method:

```
    router.get('/get_user_permission/', (req, res) => {
    pool.connect((err, client, done) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.json({ success: false, message: err});
      } else {
        client.query('select * from get_user_permission($1)', [req.decoded.userId], (err, permission) => {
          done();
          if (err) {
            res.json({ success: false, message: err });
          } else {
            res.json({success: true,permission: permission
            });
          }
        });
      }
    });
  });
```

but i get err!whats the problem?

Comment: Refer this https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/routing/router-guards/

Answer (score 0):

You should use a `[routeGuard][1]` to check permission.

your routing module look like this.

```
 path: 'viewoutgoing/:id', component: YourComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
```

RouteGuard

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

constructor(private router: Router) {


}

canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {

    if (this.if (route.params[id] === 'yourRole') {
       //Do return  true
        return true;
    }


    // not logged in so redirect to login page with the return url
    this.router.navigate(['/login'], { queryParams: { returnUrl: state.url } });
    return false;
}
```

As per your comment, you have a **multiple guards**. You can try something like this for a scenario.

```
@Injectable()
export class RoleGuard implements CanActivate {

constructor(private _authGuard: AuthGuard) {}

canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Promise<boolean> {
    return this._authGuard.canActivate(route, state).then((auth: boolean) => 
  {
        if(!auth) {
           return Promise.resolve(false);
        }
        //... your role guard check code goes here
    });
  }
```

**Routing Module**

```
 path: 'viewoutgoing/:id', component: YourComponent, canActivate: [RoleGuard ] },
```

Comment: your solution is useful but i already have an authguard to check the logged in user, i need a new guard to check the permission for user.cant you help me to create two guards? i tried to do it but when i use two guards beside each other, only the authGuard works

Comment: @fariba.j can you add what you have tried so far to the question

Comment: i solve that problem but i have a new problem now! i edited the question!can you help me?

Comment: @fariba.j please show the route configuration you have used. The canActivate accepts an array of guards so all guards have to be passed for success. The requirement of different guards is valid due to separation of concerns of different validations and is supported by Angular.               Also you have mentioned about some error, so please detail that as well.